# GUI alternative to WebHTTrack with similar functionality

Tags: software-recommendation, gui, alternative, httrack

I'm looking for other GUI alternative to `webhttrack` software with similar functionalities. Webhttrack is itself an alternative of the command line program `httrack`, but I'm not very happy using it. Is there any?

httrack is from it's man page description:

> Copy websites to your computer (Offline browser)

Comment: Your title has `WebHTTrack` but your question body asks for only the gui alternative of httrack. Have you already used WebHTTrack?

Comment: A note to reviewers: software recommendations are [on topic at AskUbuntu](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14394/are-software-recommendations-on-topic-or-not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found one Firefox add-on. It's called Scrapbook.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/scrapbook/

The Scrapbook's feature includes (from info page) -

> - Save Web page
> - Save snippet of Web page
> - Save Web site
> - Organize the collection in the same way as Bookmarks
> - Full text search and quick filtering search of the collection
> - Editing of the collected Web page
> - Text/HTML edit feature resembling Opera's Notes

I've tested it. It can save webpage and website (with custom level's of depth) and is very customizable.

Comment: Actually I'm looking for its alternative. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I'm afraid, it's the only piece of GUI alternative of httrack, though web-based.

Comment: Other gui alternative without httrack core will be okay for me. I edited my question. I think, I created some ambiguity in my previous question.

Comment: You mean with similar functionality, even if not based on httrack?

Comment: Yep, this was exactly what I meant.

Comment: I've updated the answer and you can check

Comment: This extension it is discontinued in new firefox version